# How to draw from an array on click?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, draw

I've been playing around with the JPanel below. At the moment, I've created a couple circles, one of which you can move around with the WASD keys.

The problem I am facing lies in the mouse listener. I would like to be able to click, and upon doing so, have a player created (from the "towers" array) and drawn on the location of the mouseclick, to a maximum of 30 players (it's for a tower defense game).

The code below compiles without errors, but I get a runtime error as soon as I click on the screen. I know what my mistake is, but I don't know how I can get around it.. Using this.draw(g); in the paint method returns a cannot find symbol error for draw. How can I correct my code such that I will be able to create and draw a player at the location of my mouse? If you want more info on my objects etc, I've pasted all 3 of the classes in the project over here: http://pastebin.com/cLHsRU4y

```
public class game extends javax.swing.JPanel implements KeyListener{
private int x = 20;
private int y = 20;
private int cnt = 0;
private player Player;
private player maximus;
private player[] towers;

public game() {
setFocusable(true);
addKeyListener(this);

addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
        {
          if(cnt==0)
        {
            setArray();
        }
          int mx=m.getX();
          int my=m.getY();
          towers[cnt].setX(mx);    //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
          towers[cnt].setY(my);
         // towers[cnt].draw(z);
          cnt++;


    //repaint();
          cnt++;
        }
});
Player = new player(100,100);
maximus = new player(490,300);
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(200, 22, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 907, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 521, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
public void setArray()
{
   player towers[] = new player[30];
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
       towers[i] = new player(5,5);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 20,20);
    Player.draw(g);
    maximus.draw(g);
    if(cnt>0)
    {
    towers[cnt].draw(g);
    }


    repaint();
}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        y-=1;
        Player.setYDir(-1);
    }
     if(c==KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        y+=1;
        Player.setYDir(1);
    }
     if(c==KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        x-=1;
        Player.setXDir(-1);
    }
     if(c==KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        x+=1;
        Player.setXDir(1);            
    }


}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    Player.setXDir(0);
    Player.setYDir(0);
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the proper array... in the setArray() method, you should be using this.towers [the global variable you declared and are trying to use when you get your NPE] to set instead of creating a local variable that is just going to be garbage collected at the end of the method. (How you have it right now, no elements currently exist in your array to work with).

```
public void setArray()
{
    //Use the global variable and don't create a local one
    this.towers = new player[30];
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        towers[i] = new player(5,5);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask can you provide syntax?

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my error. As a follow up question though, the towers don't actually draw on click. If you look at my paint method I've set it to draw towers[cnt] as long as cnt>0 (to avoid a null pointer exception), so it should be drawing every time I click. Why isn't it?

Comment: You will probably have to loop through all the elements in the array and call each draw method. so get rid of the if statement and the code inside and replace with : for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) { towers[i].draw(); } and it should fix that.

Comment: Yay! You have no idea how much you've helped me :D Thank you very very very much :3